# Задача на оптимизацию

Tags: оптимизация, java

Есть такая задача. Даны два текстовых файла в формате [код 8 цифр],[строка 14 символов]. Необходимо создать третий файл в котором объедены строки из первых файлов, если у них одинаковые коды.(по идее выполняется inner join)
Пример.
Первый файл
`00000001 AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
04532323 CCCCCCCCCCCCCC`

Второй файл
`00000001 BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
04532323 DDDDDDDDDDDDDD`
Результат
`00000001 AAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
04532323 CCCCCCCCCCCCCC,DDDDDDDDDDDDDD`
Нужно написать самым эффективным способом, использую не более 50 MB JVM heap. Сторонние библиотеки и прочий софт не использовать.
Кто может подсказать литературу, чтобы там были подобные задачи решены?

Comment: Во многих книгах по алгоритмам (если не во всех) описана сортировка слиянием, например. В книгах по функциональному программированию наверняка упоминается map/reduce, например :)

Comment: Информация в файлах упорядочена по ключам?

Comment: какой сейчас у Вас рабочий вариант? сколько памяти занимает?

Comment: Влезут ли два исходных файла одновременно в память? Потому как внутрення и внешняя сортировки - две большие разницы.

Comment: Рабочий вариант через ассициированный массив. При размере файла порядка миллиона записей размера кучи уже не хватает. Файл не упорядочен по ключам.

Comment: какой максимальный размер входных файлов может быть?

Comment: @stream2006 Я же вам намекнул в самом начале. Вам нужно отсортировать входные файлы алгоритмом, который позволяет это делать по частям. Затем просто пробежаться по сортированному файлу и выписать все значения для одинаковых ключей. Все.

Эффективность будет в основном зависеть от выбранного алгоритма сортировки.

Comment: @stream2006, Вам подсказать литературу?

Д. Кнут. "Искусство программирования" т.3 "Сорировка и поиск".

Читаете главу о внешней сортировке (по ходу видимо обращаетесь и к другим главам) и делаете, как советует @a_gura.

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого входного файла:
Прочитать большой кусок - но чтобы уложиться в 50 Мб - отсортировать и записать в отдельный файл.
Затем читать сразу из всех кусков (используя небольшой буфер для каждого) и сливать в один выходной файл.

Answer (score -1):

Взять какую-нить embedded DB - ну хоть Derby встроенную в Java SDK или HSQLDB, написать тупой импорт данных в 2 таблицы и сджойнить таблицы через inner join, результат выкинуть в текст.

Comment: Смысл этой задачи - не использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Поправьте тогда вопрос

Comment: Скорее смысл этой задачи не использовать большой heap, чего нельзя избежать, использую emdedded DB. И эффективность вообще - это не про embedded DB.